# How to assign value to an implementation of an interface, but the interface doesn't have setter method?

Tags: oop, interface, junit, setter

I have an interface: Show, and i have the implementation class calls ShowImpl, and also i have a implementation class calls ManageShowImpl. I have completed all the methods inside ManageShowImpl. Now i am doing Junit testing. The method i defined in the  ManageShowImpl, for example: addShows(Show... shows), now i want to assign values to the show array: Show[], but in the interface: Show, i don't have setter method(which is not supposed inside interface), can some expert tell me how can i add the value to Show[].

Comment: You can have setters in an interface.  If you really want a read-only interface, you will have to go through the ManagerShowImpl class.  If your use case is that you receive the interface type in some method or assignment and need to add shows, then you will have to add the method to the interface.  Either that or cast it; this might be reasonable since this sounds like it's in a unit test.

Comment: My case is  the parameters in all the methods of ManageShowImpl are Show(Interface), not ShowImpl(Class). Now i wanna unit testing the methods in ManageShowImpl, and don't know how to assign data to Show(Interface), but in ShowImpl, i do have setter method. Is there some way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your issue, I think you can simply set values in your constructor:

```
public class ShowImpl implements Show{

    private Show[] shows;

    public ShowImpl(Show... shows){
        this.shows = shows;
    }

    @Override
    public void someInterfaceMethod(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I am *not* a junit expert, or even a beginner, but maybe I can inspire a few to answer.  I *have* done a fair amount of testing.)

Given a class with a constructor, you can always create an instance, fill it with whatever data you want, and test it any way you want.  Interfaces are a lot more limited.  Testing aside, this is a very good thing.  It limits the damage someone can do if they get hold of an interface implementation; it safely encapulates the data.  But you cannot test an interface in isolation.  You need to create an instance of an implementing class first.  At that point you should fill in your array.  *Then* pass it to a test method as an *interface instance* to test the interface.